# Attempting to Reference a Deleted Function in Future

Tags: c++, multithreading, templates, asynchronous, future

I am writing a program that will find a large number of prime numbers asynchronously. I achieve by utilizing a `TaskQueue` which is a essentially a queue composed of futures that all execute asynchronously. There are three threads involved: a chef thread that assigns these tasks to the `TaskQueue`, a customer thread which checks to see if the futures have answers and decides whether to store the data if they do, and a main thread which launches and checks the status of the other two. I am getting an error on line 593: `Error  2   error C2280: 'std::future<return_type>::future(const std::future<return_type> &)' : attempting to reference a deleted function  e:\visualstudio\vc\include\xmemory0 593 1   MultiThreadTaskQueue` which references the file xmemory0, which seems to be a file referenced by one of the other headers that I `#include`d. My problem appears to be a problem with the copy constructor of a future object, possibly one that is deleted before it can be copied, but I am unsure where that would happen in my program. Here is a copy of my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>

using namespace std;
using longInt = long long unsigned int;

template <typename return_type>
class TaskQueue {
private:
    queue<future<return_type>> tasks;
    mutex mtx;

public:
    //return a copy of the queue
    queue<future<return_type>> copy() const {
        return tasks;
    }


    //default constructor
    //does nothing, waits for input
    TaskQueue() {
        //do nothing
    }

    //call constructors
    //adds task to queue
    template <typename ... Args, typename ... Ts>
    TaskQueue(return_type(*func)(Ts...), Args&& ... args) {
        tasks.push(std::async(func, args...));
    }

    //copy constructor
    //copies another queue to this one
    TaskQueue(const TaskQueue<longInt> & in) {
        tasks = in.copy();
    }

    //setter and getter functions

    //inserts a new task into the queue
    template <typename ... Args, typename ... Ts>
    void add(return_type(*func)(Ts...), Args&& ... args) {
        tasks.push(std::async(func, args...));
    }

    //returns true if the task at the top of the queue is ready
    bool valid() {
        return tasks.front().valid();
    }

    //gets the value, if the value is not ready, waits for it to be ready
    //pops the top task after getting it
    return_type get() {
        //mtx.lock();

        return_type temp = tasks.front().get();

        tasks.pop();

        //mtx.unlock();
        return temp;
    }

    //waits for the value of the top of the queue to become ready
    void wait() {
        tasks.front().wait();
    }

    //returns the number of tasks in the queue
    int size() const {
        return tasks.size();
    }

};

bool HALT_ALL = false;
int MAX_TASKS_AT_ONCE = 10;

//prototypes
longInt isPrime(longInt);
void cook(TaskQueue<longInt>&);
void consumer(TaskQueue<longInt>&, vector<longInt> &);

int main() {

    //declare task queue and vector to store prime numbers
    TaskQueue<longInt> checkPrimes;
    vector<longInt> primes;
    primes.push_back(2);

    int maxPrimes;

    cout << "Enter max primes: ";
    cin >> maxPrimes;
    cout << endl;



    //launch the chef thread and the customer thread
    thread chef(&cook, checkPrimes);
    thread customer(&consumer, checkPrimes, primes);

    int previousSize = 0;

    //use main to keep track of the progress of the other threads
    while (primes.size() < maxPrimes) {
        if (previousSize != primes.size()) {
            cout << "Primes found: " << primes.size() << endl;
            previousSize = primes.size();
        }
        else {
            checkPrimes.wait();
        }
    }

    //halt all other asynchronous operations
    HALT_ALL = true;

    //join other threads
    chef.join();
    customer.join();

    //print final prime found for verification of data
    cout << "Final Prime found: " << primes[primes.size() - 1] << endl;

    system("PAUSE");


    return 0;

}

//returns the number if it is prime or 0 if it is not
longInt isPrime(longInt n) {
    if (n <= 3) {
        if (n > 1) {
            return n;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    if (n % 2 == 0 || n % 3 == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    for (unsigned short i = 5; i * i <= n; i += 6) {
        if (n % i == 0 || n % (i + 2) == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return n;
}

void cook(TaskQueue<longInt>& tasks) {
    longInt currentPrime = 3;

    while (!HALT_ALL) {
        if (tasks.size() < MAX_TASKS_AT_ONCE) {
            tasks.add(isPrime, currentPrime);
            currentPrime += 2;
        }
    }
}

void consumer(TaskQueue<longInt>& tasks, vector<longInt> & primes) {
    while (!HALT_ALL) {
        if (tasks.size() > 0) {
            longInt temp = tasks.get();

            if (temp > 0) {
                primes.push_back(temp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to copy `std::future`s here:

```
queue<future<return_type>> copy() const {
    return tasks;
}
```

But `std::future` is non-copyable, its copy constructor is deleted (see for example [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/future)), so you're getting that compiler error message.

Remove `copy()` function and `TaskQueue` copy constructor.

Your mistake is actually here:

```
thread chef(&cook, checkPrimes);
thread customer(&consumer, checkPrimes, primes);
```

The `std::thread` constructor moves its arguments if they are rvalues, otherwise it copies them. So just pass `reference_wrapper`s instead:

```
thread chef(&cook, std::ref(checkPrimes));
thread customer(&consumer, std::ref(checkPrimes), std::ref(primes));
```

Not only it will make your code compile, it will make it also semantically more correct, because you probably don't want each thread to have its own task queue and vector of primes.

Note that you'll have to do proper synchronization to avoid data races.

Comment: So is it as simple as just deleting that function?

Comment: @Stephen if you don't need it - then yes, it's that simple. I believe you'll have to prohibit copying of your `TaskQueue` as well.

Comment: I deleted the copy constructor and the function copy as they were the only places i would have used it. The error still persists though.

Comment: @Stephen you don't just "delete" copy constructor, you make it `= delete`, and then the compiler will show you all the places where you are copying TaskQueue, and you have to eliminate all such errors.

Comment: I replaced my copy constructor with `TaskQueue(const TaskQueue & in) = delete;` but the compiler simply gives the same error message as above.

Comment: That allowed it to compile and also let it run, but now I am getting a debug assertion failed, where `abort()` is being called.

Comment: @Stephen yes because the access to shared variables is not synchronized, as I pointed out in my answer.